# How to Update Range within a Loop using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, object, range

I have three columns: names, accepted/synonym, synonyms of accepted names. The script is intended to cycle through the "accepted/synonym" column and when the value is equal to "accepted" a range object needs to be set to Cells(x, 9) until another "accepted" value is reached. If the following values are "synonyms" then the values of Cells(x,4) should be concatenated to the most recent range Cells(x,9) unitl reaching an "accepted" value.
I am trying to update the value of the range which should include the names of all the synonyms that come before the most recent "accepted" cell. My script is not updating the range every iteration that there is a new "accepted" row but is instead just replacing the same range value over and over. I tried to explain this as best I can, but any help is appreciated and I am prepared to clarify any details. Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim acc As String
    Dim syn As String
    Dim updRng As Range
    
    x = 157
    

    Set rng = Cells(157, 9)
    
    
    Do While x < 5000
        If Cells(x, 5).Value = "synonym" Then
            syn = Cells(x, 4).Value
            acc = acc & "; " & syn
            acc = Right(acc, Len(acc) - 2) ' "-2" the length of "; "
            rng.Value = acc '<---This is the problematic line
        Else
            Set updRng = Cells(x, 9)
            acc = ""
            If Cells(x + 1, 5).Value = "synonym" Then 'if the cell below is synonym
                updRng.Value = acc
            End If
        
        End If
        
        x = x + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I just solved it myself... Here is the mostly working code now. It seems I needed another condition, that being an "ElseIf"

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

     
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim acc As String
    Dim syn As String
    Dim updRng As Range
    
    x = 157
    'y = 9

    Set rng = Cells(157, 9)
    
    
    Do While x < 5000
        If Cells(x, 5).Value = "synonym" Then
            syn = Cells(x, 4).Value
            acc = acc & "; " & syn
            acc = Right(acc, Len(acc) - 2) ' "-2" the length of "; "
        ElseIf Cells(x + 1, 5).Value = "accepted" Then
            updRng.Value = acc
        Else
            Set updRng = Cells(x, 9)
            acc = ""
            If Cells(x + 1, 5).Value = "synonym" Then 'if the cell below is synonym
                updRng.Value = acc
            End If
        
        End If
        
        x = x + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```